# Grid Layout Spacing Issue

Tags: android, xml, grid

I have created a grid-view, in which I am displaying images. I am trying to re-create the look from the Application: 2048. However, I am experiencing several issues with the way it looks. The images are appearing as a 3x3 Grid, which is correct, however, for some reason the columns have massive gaps in between them. Here is my GridView XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:numColumns="3"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
</GridView>
```

And here is the ImageAdapter:

```
package view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import big.sound.soundtapper.R;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = { // 9 Tiles
R.drawable.bev_tile_default, R.drawable.bev_tile_default,
        R.drawable.bev_tile_default, R.drawable.bev_tile_default,
        R.drawable.bev_tile_default, R.drawable.bev_tile_default,
        R.drawable.bev_tile_default, R.drawable.bev_tile_default,
        R.drawable.bev_tile_default };

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(120, 120));
    return imageView;
}

}
```

I am trying to centre the table to the page, and get rid of the large Spaces between the columns.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: can you show ur image also??

Comment: Just a guees, may be ur images have this border around them.

Comment: If your images have the border, you can then remove or reduce `horizontalSpacing` and/or `verticalSpacing`

Comment: The image has no border around it. Ill try to make a screenshot

Comment: Change `imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(120, 120));` to something like `imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(160, 120));` or `imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`. Then you may get to know from where the gap is from.! It's just a guess.

Comment: Tried that. Update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working good for me...

```
<GridView
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
```

/>

Comment: Tried it. The gaps still exists. I dont know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

> ```
> <GridView
>     android:id="@+id/gridView1"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_margin="4dp"
>     android:columnWidth="80dp"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
> </GridView>
> ```

Comment: It has to be 3x3. Wont autofit break that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="0dp" 
android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:numColumns="3" >
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: The Gap Is still there like in the picture. Its really weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Auto-fit and also use verticalspacing and stretchmode as below. AutoFit best fils the screen and then you canplay whether to have 3x3 or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FFCC00" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnWidth="150dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform" >
        </GridView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The Gaps are still there. Im not sure what's causing that though.

Comment: Having a hard time getting a screenshot.

Comment: ... really? too hard to go to DDMS perspective, click on the emulator, click on the camera icon, then click Save and Done?

Comment: Uploaded to Question.

Comment: Try this as well to keep things in center of the page. android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical". As far as the gap between goes, try "android:clipToPadding="true" to see if any impact. If still issues, My guess is that, your images have a large borders